# Is there a module/method in Python to help identify if a Google Account is a regular account or a Google Workspace-linked account?

Tags: python, google-oauth, auth0, google-workspace, service-accounts

A little more detail on the question -

**Scenario**

The app I'm working on currently performs the following -

- Logs in users via Google OAuth ( added to Auth0 login )
- Comprises of a list of Google Sheets with their links, which the user can open when he is logged in
- When the user clicks on a sheet's link to open it, he is redirected to a page where the sheet is expected to be displayed in an iframe.
- The **gspread** module in Python retrieves the list of users the sheet has been shared with (permission list) (gspread is authenticated using a service account which helps do this). If the authenticated user is a part of the permission list, the iframe is displayed, else, an error message is displayed.

Now, the next requirement we'd like to achieve is for specific users in the site to be able to share the Google Sheet with other users, using the **share** method in the **gspread** module. However, we would like to share it with users with regular Google accounts, and not those enabled with Google Workspace, owing to business requirements which I prefer not to disclose at this point.

Is there a way to do this? I've found a something here - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python#configure_the_sample, but this is only to check with the users of the same workspace, if the service account I possess is that of the workspace's admin, but what I need to know is in general if a given account is a regular one or is linked to the workspace of any organization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The People api has a method called [people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22resourceName%22%3A%22people%2Fme%22%2C%22personFields%22%3A%22memberships%22%7D) If i pass it me and check the person fields for memberships

## Workspace domain account

```
{
  "resourceName": "people/106744391248434652261",
  "etag": "%EgMBLjcaBAECBQciDFpMNzJsdkk3SG80PQ==",
  "memberships": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "source": {
          "type": "DOMAIN_PROFILE",
          "id": "106744391248434652261"
        }
      },
      "domainMembership": {
        "inViewerDomain": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

## standard gmail user

```
{
  "resourceName": "people/117200475532672775346",
  "etag": "%EgMBLjcaBAECBQciDEdwc0JEdnJyNWRnPQ==",
  "memberships": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "source": {
          "type": "CONTACT",
          "id": "3faa96eb08baa4be"
        }
      },
      "contactGroupMembership": {
        "contactGroupId": "myContacts",
        "contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/myContacts"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So the answer is yes you need to go though the google people api.   I dont have any python examples for the people api on hand but let me know if you cant get it working.